# Fatal errors after magento update from 1.7 to 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, upgrade, fatal-error

I tried upgrading my shop from 1.7 to 1.9 but this caused sever problems on my webshop. (I did this via Magento Connect) Due to many custom made modules made by my predecessor I had no choice but to revert back to the old back upped file systen.

I tried reverting to a back up and reverted all the files on the FTP to the old version from before the update (only the files didn't revert the database yet).

Now I'm receiving this error on the site (frontend)

```
Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'METHOD_BML' in /home/users/amanvftp/amanvida.eu/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Block/Bml/Banners.php on line 75
```

In that file on line 75 is the following code

```
if (!$this->_getConfig()->isMethodAvailable(Mage_Paypal_Model_Config::METHOD_BML)
            && !$this->_getConfig()->isMethodAvailable(Mage_Paypal_Model_Config::METHOD_WPP_PE_BML)) {
            return '';
        }
```

The page stops processing there and is blank below that error.

In the backend, the admin section. I have a similar problem with the following error:

```
Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'XML_PATH_TAX_NOTIFICATION_URL' in /home/users/amanvftp/amanvida.eu/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Block/Adminhtml/Notifications.php on line 175
```

Code:

```
public function getInfoUrl()
    {
        return $this->_app->getStore()->getConfig(Mage_Tax_Model_Config::XML_PATH_TAX_NOTIFICATION_URL);
    }
```

Also in the Magento Connect it still shows "1.9.2.1 (stable) " next to the mage modules.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: If magento is saying it is 1.9.2.1 you didn't revert everything. Just apply the old backup and try again.

Comment: Is it possible that this is caused because the database isn't reverted as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that `app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php` is up do date.
[as you can see here](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php#L54), the constant is defined in that class.
maybe you copied the `Mage_Paypal_Model_Config` class in the `local` codepool for some reason and you are still using the old version of the class.  Check if you have the file `app/code/local/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php`.
If you do, you need to add the constant in that file also.
The same goes for the class Mage_Tax_Model_Config.
[You can see here](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Config.php#L42) that the constant `XML_PATH_TAX_NOTIFICATION_URL` is defined

Comment: There was nog local class but it were the core classes themselves who were missing the methods and constants. I manually added the constants and methods which were being thrown as exceptions in several classes until it deployed. Now everything seems to be running but it doesn't feel like a correct way of solving the issue to manually copy paste data into the core fils.

Comment: This means that you didn't upgrade properly, or something went wrong during the upgrade. There might be other classes like these ones.

Comment: As I said in my original comment. I upgraded, and then reverted the files back because many custom modules made by the previous Magento developers stopped functioning and were too complex to weed out. So of course the upgrade isn't functioning.